# Use an regular expression to grab part of a string in js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following string :-

> `http://myapp.local/myapp/shop/products/admin/ShopProducts%5Bproduct_name%5D//ShopProducts%5BemailNotification%5D//ShopProducts%5Bemail_user%5D//ShopProducts%5Bactive%5D//ShopProducts%5Binstant_win%5D//ShopProducts%5Bmulti_buy%5D//ShopProducts%5Bprice%5D//ShopProducts%5Bquantity%5D//ShopProducts_page/2/ajax/shopproducts-grid`

I only want to grab the last section as so on.. not this is a part of pager (needs some weird custom hack) and the page number in this case is 2 but could 2,3,4, 500...

```
ShopProducts_page/2/ajax/shopproducts-grid
```

What is the easiest way to do this using vanilla js or jquery or a structured way to grab the parts into some of an array that I'll be able to manipulate?

Comment: Can you post some examples of things you have tried already?

Comment: will there always be some double slashes `//` in the path?

Comment: Dose `/ShopProducts_page\/[0-9]+\/ajax\/shopproducts\-grid/` make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there will always be double forward-slashes `//` in the path, you can simply do this:

```
//Where string is already defined to be the path
var sections = string.split('//');
var lastSection = sections[sections.length-1];
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, and of course the `string` is `window.location.pathname`